# In CakePHP, how do I render an element from a plugin inside my controller?

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP with several global plugins. I would like to render an element from one of my plugins using a controller local to the application.

Inside APP/Controller/CustomreportController.php

```
$this->render('COPlugin.Elements/reportdates');
```

When I attempt to view the page, I receive the following error:

> Missing View Error: The view for CustomreportController::paapprovals()
>   was not found.
>
> Error: Confirm you have created the file:
>   APP/View/Plugin/COPlugin/Elements/reportdates.ctp

So you see, it wants me to create a view inside the APP itself, inside: View/Plugin/COPlugin/Elements rather than use the View I already have at: ROOT/plugins/COPlugin/View/Elements/reportdates.ctp.

How can I render the element that already exists in the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is slightly different between cake 2.0 and 2.1.  The docs outline the differences in [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#requesting-elements-from-a-plugin) section.